# avoid [object Object] sitting in main search input when we enter any value to other sub search inputs - AngularJS

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

1. I am using search filter for multiple column, In this below example i created two inputs for searching. One is for Full search and another is for only student id search. Whenever i enter value to student id field, [object Object] will sit in the full search field
2. If any value is there in full search filed means we cannot enter value to student id filed.

Please help me, Thanks in advance

```
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="myCtlr">
 <input type="text" ng-model="search" placeholder="Search All">
 <input type="text" ng-model="search.student_id" placeholder="Student ID">
 <table>
  <tr ng-repeat="student in student_data|filter:search|limitTo:'10'">
    <td>{{student.table}}</td>
    <td>{{student.student_id}}</td>
    <td>{{student.name}}</td>
  </tr>
 </table>
<div>
<script>
var app = angular.module('app',[]);
app.controller('myCtlr',function($scope, $http){
    $scope.student_data = 
[{"student_id":"12508","name":"AKILA","course":"MCA","course_fee":"0","percentage":"85","University":"","partner":"guru","infocenter":"","father":"","mobile":"1234525411","sem":"2","table":"noble_table","total_paid":"2500"}]
});
<script>
```

Check my [JSFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/sureshraj/jbn06dj8/5/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need add `$` here

```
<input type="text" ng-model="search.$" placeholder="Full search">
```

Pls check [the doc](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter).

Answer (score 1):

It happens because you are binding search.studentid to the full search, use .$ for the first one

```
<input type="text" ng-model="search.$" placeholder="Full search">
<input type="text" ng-model="search.student_id" placeholder="student id">
<table>
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/sajeetharan/1rap97f7/3/)

But if you are dealing with so many search for individual property the following would be the best way

**[UPDATED DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/lNNWzxVoYp8FJ6cpVsqR?p=preview)**

Comment: Thanks for the answer, then both work same. I need separate search for student id

Comment: @RajGopal you cannot do that until you have a directive for converting to string, i think it will be more suitalbe http://plnkr.co/edit/lNNWzxVoYp8FJ6cpVsqR?p=preview

Comment: As u said i just added .$ to full search model  thats it, Its working perfect, thank u so much.

Comment: Can you invite if it has helped